# Google Charts Type Mismatch plotting time values onto graph

Tags: laravel, time, charts, google-visualization

Hi I am trying to plot a graph using Google Charts that will show the `start_day` of a `sub_task` vs `estimated_duration`, I am using a database to retrieve my data and I am converting my data into a JSON object to plot onto the graph however I am receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 
01:00:00,02:20:00,00:20:00,02:20:00,01:23:00,02:20:00,02:20:00,01:00:00,
01:23:00,01:00:00 does not match type datetime in column index 1 
 format+en_GB,default+en_GB,ui+en_GB,corechart+en_GB.I.js:169
```

This is how I am fetching plotting my data:

```js
@extends("layouts.master")
@section("content")

<div id="visualization" style="width: auto; height: 400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>
<script>
    function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var dataTable= new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('datetime', 'Year');
    dataTable.addColumn('datetime', 'estimated_duration');
    dataTable.addRows([
  [new Date({{ json_encode($start_day) }}),{{ json_encode($estimated_duration) }} ]]);


  new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'}).format(dataTable, 0);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
     var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, {curveType: "function"});   
  }      

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


</script>
@stop
```

The data values in my database are in this format:

```js
`start_day` = `2013-02-10`
`duration` = `01:00:00`
```

In laravel i am retrieving my data in a repository as so:

```
public function subtaskDurationReport() {
      return \Auth::user()->subtasks()->limit(10)->get();
}
```

And then in my controller I pass the values to the view

```php
public function reports()
    {
    $subtask = $this->subtask->subtaskDurationReport();
    return View::make('subtasks.reports')
        ->with([
            'start_day' => $subtask->lists('start_day'),
            'estimated_duration' => $subtask->lists('estimated_duration')
        ]);
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Do i need to convert the `start_day` or the `estimated_duration` format? Any suggestions and input is valued.

Comment: 01:00:00 is not a DateTime. Datetime should be only 1 column, start_date and duration

Comment: @juvian when i change to duration i get this error: Uncaught Error: Invalid type, duration, for column

Comment: I mean you need only 1 column type dateTime, with both the date and the time

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in place of yours:

```
dataTable.addRows(new Date( {{ json_encode($start_day) }}),{{ json_encode($estimated_duration) }} );
```